# How do i write a command in windows batch command in jenkins built to run a java hello world program file

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I am new to jenkins and followed crash course from youtube and I gave following commands in jenkins build in windows command batch and saved it to print hello world line but when i run build now, it failed. what could be the reason

C:\Users\Dechen Tshering\Desktop\javaproject
javac Main.java
java Main

Comment: When you ran the command what message/response did you get? This does not look valid `javac Main.java java Main`, shouldn't it be `javac Main.java`

Comment: The built failed. I ran this program in command prompt and it was working fine. The problem is i dont how to script in windows command batch built in jenkins to build the job.